# jQuery submit and post problem

Tags: post, jquery

I have a problem where I want to make an AJAX post call before I submit a form. But the problem is that only one of them seems to work and never together. How can I make a AJAX post call and still do a post submit on my form after it is done?

I have tried to do a preventDefault and then make an success function that does element.submit but that does not work...

This is what I have at the moment, the ajax.php only updates my DB and does not return anything:

```
jQuery("#testForm").submit(function() {
 saveList();
});

function saveList()
{
 var order = jQuery("#container_q ul").sortable("serialize") + "&action=update";
 jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax.php",
  data: order
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
   $("form").submit(function(){

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                //some actions
                $("form").unbind("submit").submit();

            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#testForm").submit(function() {
 saveList();
 return false; // prevents the form to jump to another page..
});
```

Comment: Yes, but I want the page reload after the AJAX is completed. But I can only have one of them, if I do return false I can see that my ajax.php does what I want it to do.

At the moment I have made a workaround by doing this:
<a onclick="saveList();">Save</a>, skip the .submit() and add ,submit() to success (on .post).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the beforeSuccess ajax option, like this `beforeSuccess: saveList()`